# Ionic Angular. $http and geolocation.getCurrentPosition do not appear to work in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a simple iOS app using Ionic.

I have 2 bits of functionality that do not appear to work in the iOS simulator that are working fine when I run the app in chrome.

Firstly, I am using the $http service in a factory to pull in some data:

```
var harbours = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '../data/harbourData.json'
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      deferred.reject(status);
    });
    return deferred.promise;


     }

.....
return {
    all: harbours
....
}
```

and then set it in my scope in the controller with:

```
var harboursPromise = Harbours.all();
harboursPromise.then(function(response){
    console.log('response from controller', response);
    $scope.harbours = response.harbours;  
  });
```

This does not appear to execute as I do not get the data in my template, whereas I do when running the app in chrome.

Secondly, geolocation. This piece of code is working fine in the browser but not when I build and run the app in the simulator:

```
$scope.position = 'Trying to find your location...'

  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.position = position.coords.latitude+", "+position.coords.longitude;
      })
    })
  } else {
    $scope.position = "Sorry, we can't get your location";
  }
```

In the running app, it appears to have access to navigator.geolocation as $scope.position does not get changed to "Sorry, we can't get your location". I'm sure there is something fundamentally wrong that I am / am not doing. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Thank you.

Comment: is it working well on real device?

Comment: First of all you need to know what error are you getting. Put some consoles and see what are errors. If you do not know how to debug app running in device or simulator? run `ionic run` command with `-l -c`arguments, see this for detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530388/cant-get-ionic-app-to-work-while-developing-if-i-turn-off-wifi/32531258#32531258

Comment: Plus use this wrapper for plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/geolocation/ , otherwise you will have to use $apply. And you are also getting error for plugin, but your $scope is not getting updated insidecall back.