# Is there anyway to use on-screen keyboard with ionic serve?

Tags: ionic-framework

I like to use `ionic serve`command for quick changes I know nothing better than actual device for developing. But I would really like to use just the on-screen device keyboard instead of my computers hardware keyboard, is this possible? I searched in ionic forums and online with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, but other option is to use this command (change platform according to your requirement) : `ionic run android -l -c` 
This will run application in you mobile but same like `ionic serve`, any change on your computer will refresh application in your device.For this your mobile and computer should be on same network. Plus keep mobile connected through usb port while you are running application on mobile. Because all resources are served from computer.
See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530388/cant-get-ionic-app-to-work-while-developing-if-i-turn-off-wifi/32531258#32531258) for more detailed version.
Here is [documentation link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic#live-reload-app-during-development-beta) to live reload app feature of ionic cli.

Comment: thanks for answer I'll wait a bit more to see if someone else can provide a workaround if not I'll accept your answer

Comment: yeah sure, till then you can have experiment with commands i mentioned ;)